# JDI Location of all exit point of a given method

Tags: java, jdi

I'm working with [JDI api (Java Debug Interface)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/index.html) and I try to create breakpoint requests for the first line of code of a particular method, but also on all "exit points" of the method (i.e. on all "return ...;").

To [create a breakpoint request](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/request/EventRequestManager.html#createBreakpointRequest-com.sun.jdi.Location-), I need a [`Location`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/index.html?com/sun/jdi/Locatable.html) object (i.e. kind of pointer to executable code)

Getting a [`Location`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/index.html?com/sun/jdi/Locatable.html) for the first line of a method is relatively easy :

```
theTargetMethod.allLineLocations().get(0)
```

Getting a `Location` for all "exit point" is more problematic. Simply getting the last line of the method is probably not enough because the method may contains multiple `return` statements  in the middle of the body, and I need to catch those too.

I have considered using a [`MethodExitRequest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/index.html?com/sun/jdi/Locatable.html) but this will generate tons of events that I don't need because they are related to other methods of the class. (so it can do the job, but it generate a huge overhead at runtime).

So my question is : how can we get a `Location` for all exit point of a method ?

**EDIT**

Additional information

For my particular use case, I need to create breakpoint requests for a few methods, and it appears that all methods I'm interested in are all *returning void*, so it may be possible to search the "return void" instruction (b1) in method's bytecode and create a Locations objects based on all indexes of b1 in bytecode.

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? If yes, could you share your solution?